# Google Books API Cover images over HTTPS fails due to certificate error

Tags: google-api, google-books

Starting yesterday requests to cover images via https began failing with

> ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

For example:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/zaRoX10_UsMC

When trying to access the https version of the thumbnail:

https://bks1.books.google.com/books/content?id=zaRoX10_UsMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE72edPPkxV6QHjzfmvf2sug_dIzxNCI02YJVAnqRe6xPdaL1GDx5m-h_2nqbzj2ZJ_krgtSW245c0-gwIF85xUi5rJ2-v07QuQl9ker6apIdeJi27W9RVadaCBwaCqxsQPy-1rt9&source=gbs_api

In Chrome this returns a response of `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`
Safari and Firefox also are unable to load the resource due to a certificate error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the sub-sub-domain, or the encryption:

- [This is an encrypted version of the image at `https://books.google.com`](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=zaRoX10_UsMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE72edPPkxV6QHjzfmvf2sug_dIzxNCI02YJVAnqRe6xPdaL1GDx5m-h_2nqbzj2ZJ_krgtSW245c0-gwIF85xUi5rJ2-v07QuQl9ker6apIdeJi27W9RVadaCBwaCqxsQPy-1rt9&source=gbs_api), and
- [This is an unencrypted version at `http://bk1.books.google.com`](http://bks1.books.google.com/books/content?id=zaRoX10_UsMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE72edPPkxV6QHjzfmvf2sug_dIzxNCI02YJVAnqRe6xPdaL1GDx5m-h_2nqbzj2ZJ_krgtSW245c0-gwIF85xUi5rJ2-v07QuQl9ker6apIdeJi27W9RVadaCBwaCqxsQPy-1rt9&source=gbs_api)

Their certificate covers `wildcard`.google.com but not `wildcard.wildcard`.google.com.  Just speculating I'd guess that `bks1` is one of a pool of servers behind `books`.